# get count back of DateTime that where within the correct range - Joda Time

Tags: java, jodatime

I want to get the count back of DateTime that where within the correct range with Joda Time.
 I have this version at the moment which is only good to check for a specific day:

```
public int getIntFatalitiesAtDay(DateTime AtDay) {

    int resultCount = 0;

    for( Fatality f : fatalities) {
        if(Days.daysBetween(f.date, AtDay).getDays() == 0) {
                    resultCount++;
        }
    }
    return resultCount;
}
```

This was usefull when i looped threw every day. However now i go by months with:

```
for (DateTime iDate = fa.firstDate; iDate.isBefore(fa.lastDate); iDate = iDate.plusMonths(1)) { ... }
```

And now i would like to get the count of fatalities that month.
Could someone help?

(Also from that year, althought i would like to see a option aswell where it doesn't look at the year but that's less important.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java's `java.util.Date` class has methods for determining if one date is before or after another. If you convert the DateTime objects to Date objects, you can do:

```
    if (f.date.after(beginngingDate) && f.date.before(endingDate)).
```

Comment: Sorry i forgot to mention, I need it with joda time.